# google oauth prefill account email

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

How can I prefill the account when using the oauth service of the google api. It asks me to enter the email address. I have other extensions installed that already have the gmail account selected for me. This is what it looks like when I initiate it:

```
        var opts = {
            interactive: true,
            url: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${clientId}&scope=${scopeParam}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&response_type=token`
        };

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(opts, authUrl => {...});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#login-hint), `login_hint` is the authentication URI parameter you're after. So your `url` could look something like this:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${clientId}&scope=${scopeParam}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&response_type=token&login_hint=chris@gmail.com`

Bear in mind that Google will not prepopulate a fake gmail address - you need to use a real one.